# How to print the function of $f[n]==f[n]$?

Tags: equation-solving, functions, function-construction

The funciton is as follow,and `n` can be 1,2,3...

```
f[n_] := n + n^2 + n*a + (2*n + 1)*b;
f[1]
f[2]
```

`2 + a + 3 b`

`6 + 2 a + 5 b`

Now consider `f[1]` and `f[2]` as the constant and use them to solve and express `a` and `b`. **So you have to copy and paste the `f[1] == 2 + a + 3 b` and  `f[2] == 6 + 2 a + 5 b` manually, so how to realize it automatically or intelligently?**

For example when you use

```
 Clear[f]
    Solve[{f[1] == f[1],f[2] == f[2]}, {a, b}]
```

you can not realize it.

The following is the solution that can realize but yo have to copy and paste the expression manually.

```
Clear[f]
    Solve[{f[1] == 2 + a + 3 b, f[2] == 6 + 2 a + 5 b}, {a, b}]
```

`{{a -> -8 - 5 f[1] + 3 f[2], b -> 2 + 2 f[1] - f[2]}}`

Comment: I tried, but I cannot understand the question. Is the goal to print something, or is the goal to solve an equation? If the goal is so solve an equation, why are you not happy with the output of `Solve`, and what do you hope to get instead?

Comment: I have supplemented something, so can you understand better?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. I urge you to [edit] your question promptly and explain it in detail, otherwise, it will be closed as off-topic.  Please consider that `f[n]==f[n]` will evaluate to `True` regardless the definition of `f[n]`. Also, `Print` returns `Null`, so your equation in `Solve` evaluates to `Null == f[1] `.

Comment: @rhermans, I have changed and can you understand it better?

Comment: To be honest, I still don't understand. Is it your aim to recover the definition of `f` based on a series of examples of how it evaluates? Probably somebody else can give you a hand. I'm lost.

Comment: It is still not very clear, but I can begin to see what your problem is. What about using a different name for the original definition, such as `auxf[n_]:=n+n^2+n*a+(2*n+1)*b; Solve[{f[1]==auxf[1],f[2]==auxf[2]},{a,b}]`?

Comment: @rhermans,**I mean  `f[1] == 2 + a + 3 b`, in this expression, in fact the left part of equation is `f[1]` and the right part of equation is `f[1]`(as you have to use `f[n]` to get `2 + a + 3 b`）, so in this way the equation became `f[1]==f[1]`, but certainly you can not solve this kind of code, and that is the pazzle.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[n_] = n + n^2 + n*a + (2*n + 1)*b;

sol = Solve[{HoldForm[f[1]] == f[1], HoldForm[f[2]] == f[2]}, {a, b}]

(*   {{a -> -8 - 5 f[1] + 3 f[2], b -> 2 + 2 f[1] - f[2]}}   *)

sol // ReleaseHold

(*   {{a -> -8 - 5 (2 + a + 3 b) + 3 (6 + 2 a + 5 b), 
  b -> -4 - 2 a - 5 b + 2 (2 + a + 3 b)}}   *)

sol // ReleaseHold // Simplify

(*   {{a -> a, b -> b}}   *)
```

Comment: Great answer and thank yoy very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[n_] := n + n^2 + n*a + (2*n + 1)*b;

f1 = f[1];
f2 = f[2];

sol = Solve[{Inactive[f][1] == f1, Inactive[f][2] == f2}, {a, b}]
```

[image]

```
sol // Activate // Simplify

(* {{a -> a, b -> b}} *)
```

Comment: Also great answer and thank yoy very much!